# How to implement move filter on Construction Heuristic (like local search)

Tags: scheduling, optaplanner

How can I create and import a move filter on construction heuristics?

**Solution**
optaplanner at configuration may show some errors when you try to add  and  on configuration. It is possible to need one more tag or something else, but for something was missing or was doing it totaly wrong.. I finaly managed to add my filter by creating customfilter class whis implements SelectionFilter and add to the annotation of the entity class. Find in the documentation the SelectionFilter class.##

Answer (score 0):

```
<constructionHeuristic>
    <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
    <changeMoveSelector>
        <filterClass>...</filterClass>
    </changeMoveSelector>
</constructionHeuristic>
```